# MySql root login error without root in database.yml

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, root

I am getting this error in production.log on my new rails app at Hostgator:

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Sat Sep 01 16:29:56 -0500 2012
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The thing is, I don't know why it would be trying to login as "root" at all.
Here is the entire content of my database.yml file:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: mwilkes_chairsales
  user: mwilkes_seller
  password: scrubbed
  host: localhost
```

I have several Wordpress installations that share this account, but this is the only Rails app. There is not code inside any of the models or controllers yet other than the relationships.

Comment: The user root is also used if you don't specify a user at all. I assume your application is not reading the YAML-file correctly. Dig into the functions where the configuration is read into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config option is **username**, not **user**:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: mwilkes_chairsales
  username: mwilkes_seller
  password: scrubbed
  host: localhost
```

Here's the [Rails guide on configuring a database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database)

Comment: Thank you - silly mistake on my end. Much obliged for the careful eyes.